# VSC extentions do not recomend more paths or content

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem with my extentions. Recent time, It does not recommend path or content snipet. It is just show 1 content, not show more. I had already deleted and installed but it can not resolved. How can I fix? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you running the latest version v1.52 of vscode?  There was a fix in there for this.  Otherwise just drag the lower border of that suggestion box down.

Comment: It already fixed, I deleted all by IOBIT and installed again. Thanks you